# Error Updating Maven Project under eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I got this error when update Maven Project under eclipse Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. (Version: Kepler Service Release 2)
     An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
     Path must include project and resource name: /myProjectName
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked?  Have you tried anything that has produced a different error message?  What plugins (e.g. m2e) have you installed?

Comment: Right button -> Run as Maven install is working fine, but Right button -> Deploy to cloudBess I get this error "Deployment failed for pom.xml, error in opening zip file"

Comment: Does it work from the command line?  And include more error text.  There should be a stack trace, right?

Answer (score 2):

rightclick project, remove maven nature (or in newer eclipse, "Maven->Disable Maven Nature")

mvn eclipse:clean (with project open in eclipse/STS)

delete the project in eclipse (but do not delete the sources)

Import existing Maven project

SOLVED THE PROBLEM